# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout Equal item height

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I’ve faced the issue of setting the two cells in horizontal group equal height (= height of largest cell in the row). Now it looks almost like intended

[image]

But I need the left (smaller) cell’s height == right (bigger) cells height.
Label has no constrained height (so can be easily increased), only binded to superview/topview edges, image has fix height, binded to superview and label as well.
Cell’s height designed to be dynamic, there could be 1 line in first cell, and 3 lines in second, or 2 lines in both for example.

What have been done to achieve current implementation:

```
    let numOfColumns = 2

    let numOfGroups = (items.count.float / numOfColumns.float).ceil.int

    var groups = [NSCollectionLayoutItem]()

    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5),
      heightDimension: .estimated(120)
    )
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let localGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
      heightDimension: .estimated(120)
    )

    (0..<numOfGroups).forEach { _ in
      let currentGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: localGroupSize,
                                 subitem: item,
                                 count: numOfColumns)
      currentGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(8)
      groups.append(currentGroup)
    }

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
      heightDimension: .estimated(CGFloat(numOfGroups) * 120)
    )
    group = .vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: groups)
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
```

There're couple of same issues like:
[UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout equal item height using autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825443/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout-equal-item-height-using-autolayout?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and
[How to create a grid layout with equal row heights using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734337/how-to-create-a-grid-layout-with-equal-row-heights-using-uicollectionviewcomposi?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and
https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/help-with-collectionview-compositional-layout/102784 but the desired result wasn't achieved/answer wasn't provided.

Thanks in advance.

UPD: Setting item size as `.fractionalHeight(1)` while leaving group's size as it is (`.estimated(120)`), which can be considered as possible solution, makes situation even worse, setting the cell's height just to 120 unconditionally.

[image]

UPD2:

Desired layout (copied from the linked issue)

```
+------+--+------+
|~~~~~~|  |~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~|  |~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~|  |~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~|  |      |
+------+--+------+
```

Current result

```
+------+--+------+
|~~~~~~|  |~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~|  |~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~|  |~~~~~~|  
|~~~~~~|      
+------+--+------+
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. Are you saying you want the height of every cell to be whatever the height of the tallest cell is? How would any other cell know what that height is?

Comment: @matt 
1. Two cells in horizontal group(!) should be equal height, height of largest cell in the row (consider horizontal group).
2. The horizontal group is already has desired height, so I just need the smallest cell to be stretched to fill the height of group.